# Scroll up and hold on desktop?

Tags: design-patterns, scrolling, desktop-application

I am doing some research on a pattern that would allow to display more information when scrolling up, in a desktop app environment. Similar to the band's profile page on Spotify on mobile (album cover taking up the whole width), the user could scroll up and hold from the default top position to see more information temporarily. On release, it would switch back to the default view.

Have you seen this pattern on desktop and if so, where? Do you think it could be appropriate in a desktop environment? If not, why?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYAPqQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: My very first impression without any test data to prove it: very few desktop users will ever think to scroll up...

Comment: Good point. I think we could easily teach it to users though.

Comment: but, how do you "hold" on desktop?

Comment: That's my biggest concern. Using the touchpad you can hold but not using the mouse wheel...

Comment: If you are relying on the user having a touchpad, then this is basically a mobile design, not a desktop design. At least on the Mac, the touchpad is a faux-touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

I would scrap the "hold" for this idea. I would start with the "expanded" view, then on the first bit of scrolling **down** you zoom it out to the normal view. Then you scroll like normal. just make sure to always have the lower objects on the screen extend a bit out of the screen (as a visual cue that they can scroll), and they'll experience your new and amazing feature.